# Can I add html component every two elements of a list from Java model using Sighlty?

Tags: java, model, iterator, sightly

I need to iterate every two elements of a list from model Java using **Slightly**.
So I can add html components every two elements.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [HTL specification](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#226-list):

> An additional itemList (respectively <variable>List in case a custom identifier/variable was defined using data-sly-list.) identifier is also available within the scope, with the following members:
>
> - index: zero-based counter (0..length-1);
> - count: one-based counter (1..length);
> - first: true for the first element being iterated;
> - middle: true if element being iterated is neither the first nor the > * last;
> - last: true for the last element being iterated;
> - odd: true if count is odd;
> - even: true if count is even.

So, in your case, where the custom identifier is `listIcon`, you would need to test `listIconList.even` instead of `boxSPID.listIcon.even`.

For your snippet, if you want to insert a `row` for each even element:

```
<sly data-sly-test="${boxSPID.listIcon}"
     data-sly-list.listIcon="${boxSPID.listIcon}">
    ${listIconList.count} <!-- You can remove this line, it's just for debug -->
    <div class="row" data-sly-test="${listIconList.even}">
        <div class="${listIcon.iconValue}">
            ${listIcon.label}
        </div>
    </div>
</sly>
```

If you want to group together two consecutive elements into the same row, you could add the group start/end tags conditionally:

```
<sly data-sly-test="${boxSPID.listIcon}"
     data-sly-list.listIcon="${boxSPID.listIcon}">
    <sly data-sly-test="${listIconList.odd}"><div class="row"></sly>
        <div class="${listIcon.iconValue}">
            ${listIcon.label}
        </div>
    <sly data-sly-test="${istIconList.even || listIconList.last}"></div></sly>
</sly>
```

or skip one set of elements (even) and reference them by index to include them with the output (odd):

```
<sly data-sly-test="${boxSPID.listIcon}"
     data-sly-list.listIcon="${boxSPID.listIcon}">
    <div class="row" data-sly-test="${listIconList.odd}">
        <div class="${listIcon.iconValue}">
            ${listIcon.label}
        </div>
        <div class="${${boxSPID.listIcon[listIconList.count].iconValue}}" data-sly-test="${boxSPID.listIcon[listIconList.count]}">
            ${boxSPID.listIcon[listIconList.count].label}
        </div>
    </div>
</sly>
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work well because creates
<div class="row">
         <div class="${listIcon.iconValue}"> </div> 
             ${listIcon.label}
         </div>
       </div>
for each element.  I need that <div class="row"> contains two elements. I tried also with data-sly-test instead of data-sly-list because the last one makes an error.

Comment: @EmiliaSeverino, yes, `data-sly-test` is used for testing. I updated the answer with your code example, adapted and cleaned up a bit.

Comment: I try your snippet code but the output is not correct because show me a <div class='row'> with one even element. So it doesn't show me all elements but only even, one for each div. The goal is 2 elements for each div.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The original question and code snippet suggests you want to add the row on each even element. Your comments suggest you want to add a row with two elements. @EmiliaSeverino, could you paste what your expected output would be?

Comment: I updated the answer with a picture and an example. Tell me if it is clear.

Comment: I add data-sly-unwrap but it remove only div-class='row'

Comment: @EmiliaSeverino, ok, so you want to group together elements of the list into rows of two. Added two suggestions on how to do that.

Comment: I changed my question with expected output. I have explained everything clearly at the top. Can you help me agian? Thanks for your support.

Comment: @Carla, you have a small typo in your condition for ending of `<div class="row">..</div>`, it's `${istIcon...` instead of `${listIcon...` (missing a letter). I also think you have an extra/unnecessary `</div>` after `${listIcon.label}`